# Como Leer un excel en React y cargarlo a una tabla

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, excel

Hola gente que tal  necesito saber si hay manera de leer un Excel desde react y mostrarlo en una tabla , por ahora lo que pude lograr es mostrarlo pero importándolo desde un input , no me sirve porque necesito que al renderizar el componente ya este cargado el Excel … adjunto el código

Lo que me vendría excelente es saber como leer un archivo Excel desde react sin tener que meterlo desde un input

[![ADJUNTO IMAGEN DE LA TABLA CON BOOTSTRAP][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcfc0.png

AQUI ADJUNTO EL CODIGO PARA LEER EL EXCEL DESDE EL INPUT

```
class Producto extends Component {

  state = {
    file: [],
  };

  readExcel = (file) => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

      fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        const bufferArray = e.target.result;

        const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });

        const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];

        const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];

        const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);

        resolve(data);

        this.setState({
          file: data,
        });

        // console.log(this.state);
      };

      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });

    promise.then((d) => {
      // console.log(d)
    });
  };
```

AQUI ADJUNTO EL CODIGO QUE SE RENDERIZA

````
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <div className="table-responsive">

        <input
            type="file"
            onChange={(e) => {
              const archivo = e.target.files[0];
              this.readExcel(archivo);
            }}
          />
          <table className="table table-striped table-bordered  text-center shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <thead className="table-primary ">
              <tr>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Visitas Totales en Compre</th>
                <th>Producto Redireccionado</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.file.map((element) => {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <td key={element["Event Category"]}>
                      {element["Event Category"]}
                    </td>
                    <td key={element["Total Events"]}>
                      {element["Total Events"]}
                    </td>
                    <td key={element["Event Label"]}>
                      {element["Event Label"]}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Producto;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar esto para crear tu File en JS, si lo tienes en un servidor solamente debes hacer el request pertinente pero el proceso sería el mismo.

```
var f = new File([""], "filename.txt", {type: "text/plain", lastModified: date})
```

De esto también puedes obtener un Blob para facilitar su lectura en cualquier parte.

Comment: y luego donde lo puedo llamar para que me funcione cuando renderiza?